# この動作をSwiperで実現したい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper

解決方法が不明なので質問いたしました。下記のリンクのスライダライブラリを使用して
実現したいスライドがあります。
http://www.idangero.us/swiper/#.VpMcPRWLRsc

その実現したいスライドは下記のサイトにあるようなものです。
・メイン画像はスライド、クリックで変更できる
・その下に配置されたサムネイルからその画像を表示できる
http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/

Swiperでも似たような事は出来ているのですが、
Swiperのデモにあるようにサムネイルが動いてしまいます。

どなたかご教授願いますでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この様に大丈夫ですか

```js
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 10,
    });
    var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        centeredSlides: true,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        touchRatio: 0.2,
        slideToClickedSlide: true,
        autoplay: 2500,
        autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
    });
    galleryTop.params.control = galleryThumbs;
    galleryThumbs.params.control = galleryTop;
```

```css
html, body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #000;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
    .gallery-top {
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs {
        height: 20%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-active {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
           <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/img/photo1.jpg)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/img/photo2.jpg)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/img/photo3.jpg)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/img/photo4.jpg)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/img/photo5.jpg)"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/img/photo1.jpg)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/img/photo2.jpg)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/img/photo3.jpg)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/img/photo4.jpg)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://black-flag.net/devel/jQueryResponsiveFlickSlider/img/photo5.jpg)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 遅くなりました。出来ました！ありがとうございます